# How to create index using S&P api

Tags: aem, search-and-promote

Is there any way to create index through API? I could not find any documentation about index creation using S&P API. 
I do not want to let S&P to crawl my site to create index rather  I would prefer to use APIs to do it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no API for S&P that can be leveraged for the indexing purposes because S&P is basically a crawling engine.

For the sake of simplicity, think of it as a private search engine crawler where you can configure several aspects of crawling like content type, frequency, paths etc. using an interface.

You can, however, use the scripted index features to allow incremental indexing of your site or provide more finer control on crawling. This will **not** eliminate crawling as the S&P needs to crawl the site in order to extract and index the information. More details about this feature can be found here:

https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/snp/c_about_scripted_index.html

Please note that this is more of a configuration and set of commands rather than an API.